# I am trying to learn API testing through PhpUnit. I am not able to understand it's flow?

Tags: php, testing, yii, phpunit

I came across a following code and I just want to ask a few questions related to that code so I can write my own code?

The code is

```
<?php
```

`require('vendor/autoload.php');`

`class BooksTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase`

`{
    protected $client;`

```
protected function setUp()
{
    $this->client = new GuzzleHttp\Client([
        'base_uri' => 'http://mybookstore.com'
    ]);
}

public function testGet_ValidInput_BookObject()
{
    $response = $this->client->get('/books', [
        'query' => [
            'bookId' => 'hitchhikers-guide-to-the-galaxy'
        ]
    ]);

    $this->assertEquals(200, $response->getStatusCode());

    $data = json_decode($response->getBody(), true);

    $this->assertArrayHasKey('bookId', $data);
    $this->assertArrayHasKey('title', $data);
    $this->assertArrayHasKey('author', $data);
    $this->assertEquals(42, $data['price']);
}
```

}

My questions are :

1> what does this mean 'base_uri' => 'http://mybookstore.com'?

Comment: If only this was **[documented somewhere](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/quickstart.html)**.

Comment: thanks.......if this is my uri [link](http://107.20.196.252/rest/businessPage?category=SUPERHEROES&distance=50&lat=26.9204172&lc=JAIPUR&long=75.78963950000002&page=1&q=&subcategory=SUPERHEROES_NGOS&subsubcategory=) then how should i write my query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

base_uri is the uri to do the test on. In this case http://bookstore.com. In your function testGet_ValidInput_BookObject() you use get'/books' it will then look in http://bookstore.com/books.

Comment: thanks.......if this is my uri [link](http://107.20.196.252/rest/businessPage?category=SUPERHEROES&distance=50&lat=26.9204172&lc=JAIPUR&long=75.78963950000002&page=1&q=&subcategory=SUPERHEROES_NGOS&subsubcategory=) then how should i write my query.

Comment: and do I have to pass every parameter as query or I can just pass `'query' => [
                'category' => 'SUPERHEROES'
            ]`

Comment: please tell me how to test multiple api's at once.

Comment: I think you should try to take a look at the link provided by deceze in the latter comment.